# Unknown property 'jsx' in diferents files using styled-jsx

Tags: reactjs, styled-jsx

I am doing a deployment in `aws amplify` of my application but I get an error when doing the deployment on an unknown `jsx` property in the files in which I use `styled-jsx`

> screenshot 1:[image]
> screenshot 2:[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md#rule-options

You need to add the jsx/global properties to be ignored in your eslint rules

Answer (score 0):

Add ignore rule on .eslintrc.js, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  rules: {
    'react/no-unknown-property': [
      2,
      {
        ignore: ['jsx', 'global'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Related Link: [Unknown property 'jsx' found react/no-unknown-property](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40269#discussioncomment-3613483)